# Private NuGet Gallery

Tags: iis, nuget, nuget-server

I am trying to set up an internal nuget feed for my company. I have built the site and deployed it to IIS server. I can install from the site itf I manually add packages to it but I cannot push to it from the command line. When I try to I get prompted for credential (none work) then get an error that says "Cannot access a closed Stream." I have been to NuGet and read everything they propose but none of it works. I am thinking this is a server setting but I have no idea which one. Has anyone encountered this that can share the solution?

Comment: Perhaps you could get something out of this: [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ScottHanselman+%28Scott+Hanselman+-+ComputerZen.com%29)

Comment: Solved this issue by removing WebDAV and adding PUT to the web.config authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by removing WebDAV and adding PUT to the web.config authorization

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do this John, I don't suppose you could expand ?

Answer (score 0):

I just added a comment to the Github issue tracker for a similar (probably identical) problem raised there:

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/487

> This is probably a result of WebDAV being installed in IIS - it seems to interfere with the settings required for NuGet Gallery. We certainly saw a similar issue with 405 errors, and uninstalling the WebDAV module fixed the problem.